# How do you split a summing point into two?

Tags: control-system, signal-processing, linear, block-diagram

I am solving a control system example on block reduction rules and stuck on this particular step. According to me, I can move the summing point ahead of the middle block to get G4 multiplied to both but that would not get the summing points in the form that they are in the next figure. Would appreciate any help or pointers on this.
[image]

Comment: Can you draw the figure after moving the summing block ahead of the middle block ? Once you push the summing point ahead of the middle block, you will end up with two summing point *adjacent to each other with no blocks in between*. That can be redrawn as the answer figure without affecting the total system TF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with this: -

[image]

Then, with the two summing blocks in the middle area you can combine them or separate them in many ways. This for instance: -

[image]

And it's a really small step to break them into two again: -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(1) From the first Circuit:

**Y2=N+B(N*G4-Y2)** with B=G1G3+G1G2/(1+G2H1)

After some minor manipulation:

**Y2=N(1+B*G4)/(1+B)**

(2) From the second circuit:

**Y2=S(1/(1+B)**  with input at the second summer S=N(1+B*G4)

Hence, we have:

**Y2=N(1+B*G4)/(1+B)**

(3) Both results are identical.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without algebraic manipulation in a more intuitive way ?